# Getting and displaying file icon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, file, icons

when using cocoa for mac apps there is a really simple solution for getting a files icon:

```
UIImage *icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path];
```

Is there a way to do this in cocoa touch also? In my iOS app I have several files in the documents folder (pdf's, txt's, etc.) which are displayed in a tableview. I would love to display their icons there as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can use

`NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[kDocumentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:cell.fileName.text]];
    self.documentViewController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    cell.fileImage.image = self.documentViewController.icons.lastObject;`

But this is not really ideal. The icons just don't look right.